# How can I find out when Windows was last started?

Tags: windows, command-line

`systeminfo` shows when the system came up after a restart, but does not show when it comes up after a shutdown and then a power on.

For instance when I run this command:

```
systeminfo | find "Sys"
```

the output shows:

```
System Boot Time:          8/10/2018, 8:45:22 AM
```

Which was when I did a restart.

I tried a solution in the previous question:

Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational | Where { $_.Id -eq 200 }

and got these results on my laptop:

```
PS C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6.0.0> Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational | Wher
e { $_.Id -eq 200 }


   ProviderName: Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance

TimeCreated                     Id LevelDisplayName Message
-----------                     -- ---------------- -------
7/30/2018 1:54:18 PM           200 Critical         Windows has shutdown: ...
6/29/2018 9:08:40 AM           200 Critical         Windows has shutdown: ...


PS C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6.0.0>
```

I'm looking for the time I turn on the computer and the time I shut it down each day. I'd like a command line so I can collect the information into a batch file.

Comment: That activity is logged in Event Viewer.

Comment: *"systeminfo shows when the system came up after a restart, but does not show when it comes up after a shutdown and then a power on."* - Do you have a source for this?

Answer (score 3):

Open a PowerShell command prompt and enter:

`Get-WinEvent -ProviderName Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-boot -MaxEvents 10 | Where-Object {$_.id -eq "27"}`

Which will return:

```
ProviderName: Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Boot

TimeCreated                      Id LevelDisplayName Message
-----------                      -- ---------------- -------
3/6/2021 1:00:00 PM              27 Information      The boot type was 0x1.
```

In the Message field you'll see one of these boot types:

```
Boot             Type Description
0x0              cold boot from full shutdown
0x1              hybrid boot (fast startup)
0x2              resume from hibernation
```

If you restarted the boot type will be `0x0`.

If you shut down and then started the boot type will be `0x1` (assuming you have `Fast Startup` enabled which is the default)